# How to set error message position in jquery Validation Engine plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validation-engine

Am using to Validation Engine2.2 jquery plugin to validate my form, the problem is I couldn't able show the error exactly on the field there a little gap comes between each field and its error message, is there any to set the top position manually for those error messages?

Answer (score 2):

By default the plugin comes with CSS properties that are set to default values, You need to override these values by giving `!important;` property for your manually created styles.

Answer (score -2):

override the property padding-top for formError class in style